# Are C# property setter critical regions?

Tags: c#, multithreading, race-condition

My question is very short:
Are C# property setter critical regions, or should I implement critical regions myself?

Here is some sample code:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int _myProperty;

    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return _myProperty; }

        set
        {
            //required: start critical section 
            _myProperty = value;
            Do1();
            Do2();
            //required: end critical section 
        }
    }

    protected virtual void Do1()
    {
        //...
    }

    protected virtual void Do2()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no magic thread fairy that will take care of thread-safety for you, you must add it yourself.  The *lock* keyword gets the job done.

Comment: @HansPassant You mean the magic *thread* fairy ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, properties are **not** implicitly thread-safe.

One reason is that for thread-safety of non-atomic operations, **you need to lock a monitor object** (as in the `lock` statement). Which object this is, and for how long it's locked, depends on your requirements. Thus, the compiler can't decide that for you automatically.

Another reason is that thread safety has **considerable performance costs**. If you don't have concurrent code, these costs would come at no benefit. Thus, the compiler doesn't make that decision for you automatically either.

*(In fact, there is nothing special about properties. They are typically implemented as ordinary get/set methods. Any special treatment in syntax and in the tools is simply by convention.)*

Answer (score 2):

You should implement critical regions yourself, because it could be that a context switch occurs after your thread has set the property but before you processed Do1() and Do2(). Another thread which gets processing time could overwrite your property now.

Use a lock to secure the setter:

```
private Object setMyPropertyLock = new Object()

public int MyProperty
{
    get { return _myProperty; }

    set
    {
        lock(setMyPropertyLock)
        {
            _myProperty = value;
            Do1();
            Do2();
        }
    }
}
```